# How to work with new classes while being backward compatible in android?

Tags: java, android, backwards-compatibility

I need to use CookieManager class for devices with version 9 or above. My code simply looks like this;

```
public class HttpUtils {
private static CookieManager cookie_manager = null;

@TargetApi(9)
    public static CookieManager getCookieManager() {
        if (cookie_manager == null) {
            cookie_manager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookie_manager);
        }
        return cookie_manager;
    }
}
```

When i run this on a 2.2 emulator; i have this error log;

```
Could not find class 'java.net.CookieManager', referenced from method com.application.utils.HttpUtils.getCookieManager
```

When i need a CookieManager i call this method with checking the os version;

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
  ...
```

So; in my app if the version is 2.2 or lower; this method is never called. My question is why am i seeing this error log?

Comment: I remove `@TargetApi(9)` from your code and run it on 2.1 emulator,and it works without any error.

Comment: @hasanghaforian; it doesn't throw an exception, but there is this error log i mentioned. Have you seen it? And did you debug the app or just run it?

Comment: I debuged it with no error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this on a 2.2 emulator if I create an instance of HttpUtils in the code of the calling Activity outside of the SDK check.  For example:

```
HttpUtils utils = new HttpUtils();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
{
    Object test = utils.getCookieManager();
}
```

If does NOT occur if I instead call the static method directly:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
{
    Object test = HttpUtils.getCookieManager();
}
```

If you have other non-static stuff in your HttpUtils class, you'll have to move the CookieManager parts to a different helper class and only call it statically...or instantiate HtppUtils after your SDK check:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9)
    {
        HttpUtils utils = new HttpUtils();
        Object test = utils.getCookieManager();
    }
```